# Power Bi - Add Total Average column in Matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi, average, metrics

Hi I am trying to add a AVERAGE column in a matrix, but when I put my metric added the average per column, but I need a total AVERAGE and total at the end just once

What I have:
[image]

What I need:

| Group | Maria | Pedro | average | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 4 | 6 | 5 | 10 |
| Second | 5 | 10 | 7.5 | 15 |

Regards

Comment: It's not clear how your "have" and "need" tables are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example detailed in the sample data table, to get the Total you could add the following measure;

```
Total By Group = CALCULATE( SUM(AverageExample[Maria]) + SUM(AverageExample[Pedro]))
```

and to average

```
Average By Group = [Total By Group] / 2
```

Based on the first three columns, this will provide

[image: Total and Average]

Comment: Hi the problem that I have is that those names as maria, pedro can be more than just one its a variable.

Comment: Can you provide a representative small example set of data or pbix file to work against?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a DAX table (or Power Query) and a designated measure.

```
Matrix Table = 
UNION(
    DATATABLE("Detail", STRING, "Detail Order", INTEGER, "Type", STRING, {{"Average", 1000, "Agregate"}, {"Total", 1001, "Agregate"}}),
    SUMMARIZE('Your Names Table', 'Your Names Table'[Name], 'Your Names Table'[Name Order], "Type", "Names")
)
```

This should give you a table with the list of people and 2 more lines for the agregations.

After that, you create a measure using variables and a switch function.

```
Matrix Measure = 
var ft = FIRSTNONBLANK('Matrix Table'[Type], 0) 
var fd = FIRSTNONBLANK('Matrix Table'[Detail], 0)
return SWITCH(TRUE,
    ft = "Names", CALCULATE([Total], KEEPFILTERS('Your Names Table'[Name] = fd)),
    fd = "Total", [Your Total Measure],
    fd = "Average", [Your Averagex Measure]
)
```

The rest is up to you to fiddle with orders, add any agregate measures and whatnot.

Note that the Matrix Table should have no relation with any table from your model.

You can also hide it and the Matrix measure.